# Can't get my compiled latex pdf to work on Acrobat

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I have a big problem. For the first time ever I decided to create a document via LaTeX and everything worked just fine, I could compile it to pdf and view it in the built in viewer (I'm using TexWorks). However, I can't open the document in adobe acrobat, can someone help me ?

EDIT: I also need anybody to open my document normally.

EDIT 2: Problem solved, I simply didn't see the error the compiler warned me about...

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unspecified error now resolved by OP.

Comment: Upvoted for OP finding out how to check for compilation errors !